# does ruby on rails have an Admin section generation feature like django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

does ruby on rails have an Admin section generation feature like django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails calls it scaffolding.

You can find more data [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding).